# Cropping image around mammogram object

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

A bit of context:

I have several mammogram images of breasts (CBIS-DDSM) which I want to crop to content, where the content in this case is not just the nonzero parts of the image, its the breast area which is a little bit below the pectoral muscle (without the pectoral muscle)

Now, I managed to remove the pectoral muscle using hough lines, but cropping to content is a bit tricky. This is what I found:

```py
def adjust_rotate(image):
    x, y = np.nonzero(image)
    xl,xr = x.min(),x.max()
    yl,yr = y.min(),y.max()
    dst = image[xl:xr+1, yl:yr+1]
    return dst
```

This code will get rid of the surrounding black pixels. As you can see from the images below, it includes the area above the breast region which is what I am trying to remove.

Instead of cropping to the minimum and maximum, I tried to crop from the middle index on the y-axis but it does not seems to work:

```py
def adjust_rotate(image):
    x, y = np.nonzero(image)
    median = numpy.argsort(y)[len(y)//2]
    xl,xr = x.min(),x.max()
    yl,yr = y.min(),y.max()
    dst = image[xl:xr+1, median:yr+1]
    return dst
```

When cropping to nonzero indices the top left corner is considered since its not zero, which leaves me images that look like this:

Original Image with pectoral muscle not removed:

[image: Original image 1]

Cropped Image with pectoral muscle removed (notice the top left area):

[image: 1 Cropped to content]

Original Image with pectoral muscle not removed:

[image: Original image 2]

Cropped Image with pectoral muscle removed (notice the top left area):

[image: 2 Cropped to content]

What I want:

Notice how only the breast region is not removed:

[image: Removed and cropped 1]

This is a better example since its almost flush with the y-axis:

[image]

Uncropped images:

The images are of large size, I am uploading a screenshot instead of the actual files:

[image]

[image]

EDIT: clarifying more and adding example uncropped images.

Comment: We are all not medically trained. So it is hard to understand your issue since you did not post an uncropped image for us to see what you start with. Nor have you explained which one if any are correctly cropped. Please explain a bit further with proper examples.

Comment: My bad. What I meant to say by the second and fourth images is that they are the uncropped images after only removing the pectoral muscle. An example of an uncropped image would be the same image but with black pixles to the right (about 50 of them). What I want is sort of unrelated to medical images, how do I crop an image to nonzero values such that the index of the minimum y axis would be in the middle and not top left.

Comment: Sorry, please post and example of the uncropped image and the desired crop. I do not understand where you want to crop or what the issue is. A picture would really help understand.

Comment: @fmw42 I hope its more clear now.

Comment: Sorry, my confusion is understanding your cropping condition regarding "how do I crop an image to nonzero values such that the index of the minimum y axis would be in the middle and not top left." Can you point out or draw an example showing how this should work?

Comment: Take a look at picture number 4, notice how this crop perfectly contains all of image. Now, the desired crop of this particular example is image number 6, where the crop on the x-axis is the same is the image before, but the y-axis crop does not start from the origin, instead, it start from the first nonzero pixel in the middle region of the image.

Comment: Sorry to be so dense, but I do not understand and am not sure about your counting. Was it only the b/w images or did it include the first color image. Can you draw a box on the large image showing where you want to crop and explain that.

Comment: I'm trying to guess what "crop ... such that the index of the minimum y axis would be in the middle" means. Maybe you just want to add `n` columns of black pixels to the left side of the image to make the breast content appear more centered in the image? If so, use `np.pad(img, ((0,0), (n, 0)))` where `img` is a 2D grayscale image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from skimage import feature
from imageio import imread
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from skimage.transform import hough_line, hough_line_peaks, rotate
import numpy as np

image0 = imread("rRTtj.png")

# canny edge detection (show muscle boundary) 
image = feature.canny(image0[:,:,1], sigma=2)

# https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html
# Classic straight-line Hough transform
# Set a precision of 0.5 degree.
tested_angles = np.linspace(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 360, endpoint=False)
h, theta, d = hough_line(image, theta=tested_angles)

# Generating figure 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(10, 6))
ax = axes.ravel()

ax[0].imshow(image0, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[0].set_title('Orig')
ax[0].set_axis_off()

ax[1].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[1].set_title('Edge detection')
ax[1].set_axis_off()


angle_step = 0.5 * np.diff(theta).mean()
d_step = 0.5 * np.diff(d).mean()
bounds = [np.rad2deg(theta[0] - angle_step),
          np.rad2deg(theta[-1] + angle_step),
          d[-1] + d_step, d[0] - d_step]
ax[2].imshow(np.log(1 + h), extent=bounds, cmap=cm.gray, aspect=1 / 1.5)
ax[2].set_title('Hough transform')
ax[2].set_xlabel('Angles (degrees)')
ax[2].set_ylabel('Distance (pixels)')
ax[2].axis('image')

ax[3].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
ax[3].set_ylim((image.shape[0], 0))
ax[3].set_axis_off()
ax[3].set_title('Detected lines')

peaks = [p for p in zip(*hough_line_peaks(h, theta, d))]
_, angle, dist = peaks[0]
# The origin is the top left corner of the original image. X and Y axis are horizontal and vertical edges respectively.
# The distance is the minimal algebraic distance from the origin to the detected line.

#print(angle, dist)
(x0, y0) = dist * np.array([np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)])
slope = np.tan(angle + np.pi/2)
#print((x0, y0, angle, slope))

ax[3].axline((x0, y0), slope=slope)

# rotate and crop
image = rotate(image0, angle*180/np.pi, center=(0,0), resize=True)
image = image[:,int(dist):]  #
ax[4].imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```